# Проблема с процедурой в MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Добрый день. У меня есть табличка заказы:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для каждого заказа существует список заказанных товаров: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также есть табличка товар, в которой указывается стоимость товара, скидка на товар и дата действия этой скидки:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Задача написать процедуру, которая будет выводит итоговую стоимость каждого заказа по фамилии клиента. У меня не получается учитывать дату действия скидки, то есть скидка учитывается всегда, независимо истекла она или нет. Если использовать использовать CASE, то приходится добавлять в Group by Дату начала действия скидки и дату конца скидки, то вывод нарушается так как еще группируется по дате:

```
SELECT @familiya as Фамилия, b.[Номер заказа], 
            CASE 
            WHEN c.[Дата конца действия скидки] < b.[Дата заказа] AND c.[Дата конца действия скидки] > b.[Дата заказа] THEN 
                (sum(c.[Цена за единицу товара] / 100 * (100 - IsNULL(c.[% скидки], 0)) * v.[количество заказанных товаров]))
            WHEN c.[Дата начала действия скидки] > b.[Дата заказа] AND c.[Дата конца действия скидки] < b.[Дата заказа] THEN    
                (sum(c.[Цена за единицу товара] * v.[количество заказанных товаров]))
            END AS Стоимость
FROM заказ b inner join заказанныетовары v ON b.[Номер заказа] = v.[Номер заказа]
    inner join товар c ON v.[Код товара] = c.[Код товара] inner join клиент k ON b.[Код клиента] = k.[Код клиента]
WHERE k.[Фамилия клиента] = @familiya 
GROUP BY b.[Номер заказа], b.[Дата заказа], c.[Дата начала действия скидки], c.[Дата конца действия скидки]
```

Без учета даты начала и конца действия скидки у меня получилось вот так:

```
SELECT @familiya as Фамилия, b.[Номер заказа], 
                (sum(c.[Цена за единицу товара] / 100 * (100 - IsNULL(c.[% скидки], 0)) * v.[количество заказанных товаров])) AS Стоимость
FROM заказ b inner join заказанныетовары v ON b.[Номер заказа] = v.[Номер заказа]
    inner join товар c ON v.[Код товара] = c.[Код товара] inner join клиент k ON b.[Код клиента] = k.[Код клиента]
WHERE k.[Фамилия клиента] = @familiya 
GROUP BY b.[Номер заказа], b.[Дата заказа]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *Если использовать использовать CASE, то приходится добавлять в Group by Дату начала действия скидки и дату конца скидки* Переместите расчёт (цены) стоимости за каждый отдельный товар заказа в CTE (предложение WITH), а в запросе уже группируйте и суммируйте.

Comment: Уберите все групповые функции из case, пусть возвращают данные каждой конкретной строки, после чего заключите весь case целиком внутрь одного sum, как то так: `sum( c.[Цена за единицу товара] * v.[количество заказанных товаров] * (case when дата-подходит then 1 / 100 * (100 - IsNULL(c.[% скидки], 0) else 1 end) )`

Comment: @Akina , спасибо!

Comment: @Mike , спасибо!